Obtain kernel module version from userspace
I'm writing a set of programs to run performance tests on a hardware device. I would like to be able to save version information for each of those subprograms inside of my main 'controller' program, so that it can be saved inside the test report. One of these subprograms is a simple kernel driver.
I know Linux kernel modules can expose version information using the MODULE_VERSION macro. This property can subsequently be read using modinfo on the command line.
Would it possible to access this information inside a C userspace program, and if so, how ?
I thought about exposing the version inside a character device from which I could read, but given the module file contains that information, it would be much more convenient to read that directly.

You could look at how modinfo does it. It doesn't look like much fun.

@pmacfarlane Certainly doesn't look crystal clear to me haha

The version string of the loaded module should be in /sys/module/<modulename>/version if it exists (where <modulename> is the name of the module, with hyphens replaced with underscores). You can read the contents of that file using C standard I/O functions or POSIX file I/O functions. There may also be a srcversion file that contains a 23 hex digit string constructed from 92 bits of the 128 bit MD4 sum of the source code.

First of all, MODULE_VERSION() is discouraged from using for years, second, we have build-id nowadays which is more important, but usually it’s enough to have a kernel version at hand. Also note the existence of modinfo tool.

Indeed, accessing the sysfs with standard I/O functions would be a simple way to achieve it !
@0andriy Why is MODULE_VERSION() discouraged, I couldn't find any info online ? I know modinfo exists, I mentioned it in my original post

@0andriy MODULE_VERSION() may be discouraged for in-tree modules, but is still useful for out-of-tree modules.

@IanAbbott It appears your solution will be the way to go for me ! Just one file I/O operation at the start of the program is not particularly costly, and it makes acquiring the version really easy.

@rickastley https://lore.kernel.org/netdev/20191212133613.25376-1-info@metux.net/ read to the end, where you can find the links to what Greg KH and Linus Torvalds think about this.

@IanAbbott, OOT modules are also discouraged.

@0andriy Discouraged for COTS hardware, maybe. There are a lot of bespoke systems out there using specially designed bespoke hardware components that require similarly bespoke drivers. Those would just litter up the kernel sources and add to the overall maintenance burden.

Then we don't care about that at all. There is a positive feedback from Greg KH, in particular, to just get rid of MODULE_VERSION() completely.

@0andriy It depends who "we" are. I'm very much on the outskirts of kernel development (although I am in the maintainers list) and do of course submit patches to the kernel where relevant, but the company I work for does design custom hardware for customers that needs drivers that nobody else will use and is of no interest to the general Linux user base.
